# heroku not setting cookies on node application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, cookies

I have set up my react app on xxx.herokuapp.com, and my node app on yyy.herokuapp.com. Both are working, and I am the backend is able to send data to the front end. But when I want to send a cookie, no cookie is set. It works during local host, but not in production. I am also using cookieParser for cookies. Here is the code:

index.js:

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: [
      "http://localhost:3000",
      "https://xxx.herokuapp.com",
      "https://yyy.herokuapp.com",
    ],
    credentials: true,
  })
);
```

auth.js:

```
export const signin = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username });
    if (!user) return next(createError(404, "User does not exist!"));

    const verifyPassword = bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password);
    if (!verifyPassword) return next(createError(400, "Invalid credentials!"));

    const token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, process.env.JWT_KEY);
    const { password, ...others } = user._doc;

    res
      .cookie("access_token", token, {
        httpOnly: true,
      })
      .status(200)
      .json(others);
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};
```

react:

```
const handleLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(loginStart);

    try {
      setOpen(true);
      setAlert({ message: "Logged in.", severity: "success" });
      const res = await axios.post(`${SERVER_URL}/auth/signin`, userForm, {
        withCredentials: true,
      });
      dispatch(loginSuccess(res.data));
      navigate("/");
      // window.location.href = "/";
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(loginFailure());
      setOpen(true);
      setAlert({
        message: error.response.data.message,
        severity: "error",
      });
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to put {sameSite: "none",
secure: true} in the res.cookie